# Execute Java module after python script execution?

Tags: java, python, mpxj

i divided my app development into three modules which needs to be done in 2 languages(Python and java) I have developed one script in python for downloading attachments from a confluence page, But unfortunately i had to develop the other module in JAVA. I need to call the java instance after the python script completed its execution. Is it possible ?.

Comment: It's not really clear what your program is, but one option is two call the java program from Python with `subprocess`.

Comment: Yeah the program i am developing with java is using MPXJ dependency , and i tried with subprocess but the dependency is not loading

Comment: Post your current code, try to make it a [example]...

Comment: Why not use a bash script to run your programs in order?

Comment: Is it possible to have parameter from python to java if i use bash script?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring with Java you can use @PostConstruct annotation where you run your python script. The annotated method called after the initialization of your component. As an example:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyAmazingComponent {


    @PostConstruct
    private void callScript() {
        Process process;
        try{
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"path/script_python.py","arg1","arg2"});
        
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception " + e.toString());
        }

     }
    
    public void doSomething(){...}

}
```

You need below dependencies for above code (if you use maven of course and versions are not must, you can change them):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```